# Sometimes cannot boot because a disk is mounted under the wrong /dev number

Tags: arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, devices

Hopefully this is not a duplicate question, I have found some similar ones but none that exactly match.

I have an Arch Linux installation dual booted alongside a Windows installation, both on different partitions of one nvme drive. I also have another nvme drive which I have mounted on my Arch installation for mass storage.

Regularly, the main nvme is /dev/nvme0n1, and the second one is /dev/nvme1n1. However, I know that it is not good to rely on these names, so my fstab looks like this:

```
UUID=1f881779-23ee-413a-a8c9-224e99f81dd4   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1
UUID=0472-C69D                  /boot/efi   vfat        defaults    0 2
UUID=abe217d2-7a93-4a2f-8d34-af8ba627cdd3   /home/j4cobgarby/Documents/.mass_storage    ext4    rw,relatime 0 3
```

The UUID beginning 1f88 is the correct partition of the main drive, and the one beginning abe2 is the correct partition of the mass storage drive.

My problem is that sometimes (and only sometimes) when I boot, the console says something equivalent to "Waiting 10 seconds for device /dev/nvme0n1p5" (p5 of this drive is the Linux partition), and then eventually it goes into a recovery shell. If the main drive is instead called /dev/nvme1n1, which sometimes happens I suppose, then partition 5 of /dev/nvme0n1 doesn't exist, which I believe is why this error is printed.

But, I don't see why it should be looking for this partition by its device name, since I specified the drives by UUID in the fstab.

For reference, here's the output of `lsblk` when the system boots properly:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme1n1     259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0 465.8G  0 part /home/j4cobgarby/.mass_storage/Documents/.mass_storage
nvme0n1     259:2    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:3    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:4    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:5    0   561G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:6    0     2G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:7    0 390.6G  0 part /
```

It's difficult to reproduce this issue since it doesn't happen very frequently, but I'll try and restart a few times now and see if it happens, and update the question if it does to give some extra information.

Comment: looks like your fstab is right, but your bootloader's linux command line or your initrd (whatever defines what your root partition actually is – it can't be /etc/fstab, because that is *on* that partition, so you need to mount that first to read it)

Comment: initrd usually has a copy of /etc/fstab and other stuff required to boot successfully (kernel modules, config files, various utilities, etc).  if the initrd hasn't been updated recently (i.e. since the OP started using UUIDs in fstab), it's probably worth updating it.  Dunno how that's done on arch, but on debian it's done by running `update-initramfs` - this is run automatically when a kernel-image or dkms package or other boot-related packages are updated, and it can be run as root whenever necessary.

Comment: This seems likely, I've ran mkinitcpio to update the ramdisk and I'll see if that fixes it! Of course, it's hard to know if it will yet, but I reckon there's a good chance. Thanks!